# Create event not working in Laravel 4 raw db statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to run a query after 5 minutes using Laravel's DB::statement() method, but I can't get it to work. The query seems to run since there are no errors given, but the event isn't created in MySQL.

Here's the code:

```
DB::statement('
    CREATE EVENT delinactief
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
    DO
        BEGIN
            UPDATE advertenties SET inactief = 0 WHERE id = :id;
        END
', array('id' => $adv->id));
```

I tried using DELIMITER in the query but that would give me errors.

Comment: Does it work when you execute query on database itself (in phpMyAdmin or MySQL console)?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Yes, it runs in Sequel Pro if I add DELIMITER | at the start and DELIMITER ; at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove BEGIN and END.

```
DB::unprepared('
    CREATE EVENT delinactief
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
    DO
    UPDATE advertenties SET inactief = 0 WHERE id = :id;
', array('id' => $adv->id));
```

Comment: 1. Try replacing :id with some static id.
2. If you receive any error, please mention here.

Comment: I get this error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2030 This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet (SQL: CREATE EVENT delinactief ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 SECOND DO UPDATE advertenties SET inactief = 0 WHERE id = 24; ), so I think it means Laravel doesn't support this command yet..

Comment: That means that PHP connector does not support such query and you must execute it manually or you're out of luck.

Comment: Use unprepared instead of statement

Comment: Using unprepared instead of statement worked! Thanks!!

Comment: Unprepared will work, however you can't bind params then obviously, right?

Comment: Yes, you cant bind params then, but that isnt a problem in my particular situation